# How to modify a foreach iteration variable from within foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach, iteration, variable-assignment

When I try to do this...

```
Item[,] array = new Item[w, h];  // Two dimensional array of class Item, 
                                 //   w, h are unknown at compile time.
foreach(var item in array)
{
    item = new Item();
}
```

...I get `Cannot assign to 'item' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'`.

Still, I'd like to do that.

The idea is to assign default `Item` class values to existing item.

Comment: Why dont you just use another variable?

Comment: `var myItem;
foreach (var item in twoDimArray)
myItem = new Item();`

Comment: It's not clear what you're really trying to achieve. Are you hoping to change the contents of the array?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Okay, now that we know your *aim* instead of how you were trying to achieve it, it's much easier to answer your question: you shouldn't be using a `foreach` loop. `foreach` is about *reading* items from a collection - not changing the contents of a collection. It's a good job that the C# compiler makes the iteration variable read-only, otherwise it would have let you change the value of the *variable* without that actually changing the collection. (There'd have to be more significant changes to allow changes to be reflected...)

I suspect you just want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        array[i, j] = new Item();
    }
}
```

That's assuming it's a rectangular array (an `Item[,]`). If it's an `Item[][]` then it's an array of arrays, and you'd handle that slightly differently - quite possibly with a `foreach` for the outer iteration:

```
foreach (var subarray in array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < subarray.Length; i++)
    {
        subarray[i] = new Item();
    }
}
```

Comment: Lets see if this old answer will get some attention. Your answer is obvious for a 2-dimensional array but is there a clever answer for an n-dimensional array?

Comment: @LamdaComplex: Well you could build an array of indexes, and effectively increment that - or use recursion. I suggest you ask a new question, with a short but complete example of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6):

Not knowing the size isn't a problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < twoDimArray.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        twoDimArray[i, j] = ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to initialize the array. *You can't do that this way*. Instead, you need to loop through the array by index.

To initialize the elements of a given two-dimensional array, try this:

```
for (int d = 0; d < array.GetLength(0); d++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(1); i++)
    {
        array[d, i] = new Item();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use normal for loop for that.

Comment: it's a two-dimensional array, so you can *find out* the length, right?