# How can i assign a value to a char variable in a foreach loop? C#

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, char, stringbuilder

I am trying to do is something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(char ch in valor)
{
    if (ch == ',')
        ch = '.';
    else if (ch == '0' || ch == '1' || ch == '2' || ch == '3' || ch == '4' || ch == '5' || ch == '6' || ch == '7' || ch == '8' || ch == '9' || ch == ',')
    {
        sb.Append(ch);
    }
}
```

What I want is, if the character is a comma, to make it a dot. But i get the following error

> it is not possible to assign value to 'ch' because it is a foreach interaction variable

Comment: What is the end goal? Also `ch == ','` is present both in `if` and `else if` which does not make much sense.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11810794/1997232).

Comment: The lang spec explicitly states _"The variable v is read-only in the embedded statement."_ but not why. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-foreach-statement

Comment: alternative approaches `if ("0123456789.".Contains(ch))` or `if (char.IsDigit(ch) || ch == '.')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not append in both if branches?

```
foreach(char ch in valor)
{
    if (ch == ',')
    {
        sb.Append('.');
    }
    else if (ch == '0' || ch == '1' || ch == '2' || ch == '3' || ch == '4' || ch == '5' || ch == '6' || ch == '7' || ch == '8' || ch == '9')
    {
        sb.Append(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or use `string.Replace( ",", ".")` prior to the foreach?

Comment: Oh God, don't know how I didn't think about it... Thanks!

Comment: @Fildor Yes, that's how I would do it, but the question was a little different. There are probably 100 million ways to do it.

Comment: Absolutely. It's just the first thing that came to my mind... Also, _to me_ the question seems a little like "how can I do x, while I am not allowed to do x" ... so hard to answer, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just introduce a local variable

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(char ch in valor)
{
    var tmp = ch == ',' ? '.' : ch;

    if (char.IsDigit(tmp) || tmp == '.')
    {
        sb.Append(tmp);
    }
}
```

You can also use the static `char.IsDigit()` method to check whether a char is a digit or not

You could also do it only with linq:

```cs
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb = valor
    .Select(c => c == ',' ? '.' : c)
    .Where(c => char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.')
    .Aggregate(sb, (sb, c) => sb.Append(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer*: **it is impossible**.

Using an immutable `foreach` indexed item you need to use an intermediate variable like that:

```
foreach ( char ch in valor )
{
  char c = ch;
  if ( c == ',' )
  {
    c = '.';
  }
  if ( c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4'
    || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9'
    || c == '.' )
  {
    sb.Append(c);
  }
}
```

I removed the `else` because it seems to be a mistake...

But in this case you may prefer directly use a `for` to avoid this useless intermediate variable and so to optimize speed and memory:

```
for (int index = 0; index < valor.Length; index++)
{
  char c = valor[index];
  if ( c == ',' )
  {
    c = '.';
  }
  if ( c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4'
    || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9'
    || c == '.' )
  {
    sb.Append(c);
  }
}
```

Next, in the case of the code provided, we can refactor like that, using the `else` in the right way now:

```
for (int index = 0; index < valor.Length; index++)
{
  char c = valor[index];
  if ( c == ',' )
  {
    sb.Append('.');
  }
  else
  if ( c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4'
    || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9' )
  {
    sb.Append(c);
  }
}
```

Also, in the case of the code provided, we can improve to this:

```
for ( int index = 0; index < valor.Length; index++ )
{
  char c = valor[index];
  if ( c == ',' )
  {
    sb.Append('.');
  }
  else
  if ( char.IsDigit(c) )     // or IsNumber
  {
    sb.Append(c);
  }
}
```

And to optimize better:

```
for ( int index = 0; index < valor.Length; index++ )
{
  char c = valor[index];
  if ( c == ',' )
  {
    sb.Append('.');
  }
  else
  if ( c >= '0' && c <= '9' )
  {
    sb.Append(c);
  }
}
```

So using a `foreach` we can write, but a little less optimized while being more clean:

```
foreach (char ch in valor )
{
  if ( ch == ',' )
  {
    sb.Append('.');
  }
  else
  if ( ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' )
  {
    sb.Append(ch);
  }
}
```

[Char.IsDigit Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit)

[Char.IsNumber Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber)

[foreach, in (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)

[for (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var valor = "google,com1234";

if (valor.Contains(','))
{
   valor = valor.Replace(",", ".");
}
foreach (char ch in valor)
{
   if (ch == '0' || ch == '1' || ch == '2' || ch == '3' || ch == '4' || ch == '5' || ch == '6' || ch == '7' || ch == '8' || ch == '9' || ch == '.')
    {
        sb.Append(ch);
    }
}
```